# Is it possible to play on friend's world in a different part of the country?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I live in different parts of the country.  Is there some way that I can play on his world?

Answer (score 3):

Your friend will need to be running a server for you to connect to, with his world, or you create one and start on it together. There are utilities for running a server using your PC, and also a (separate) paid application that you can use on iOS to host the server.

**PoketMine (PC program)**

[(link to project page)](http://www.pocketmine.net/)

You can use this application on your home computer to run a server, that your friend will be able to connect to. This requires that you have a stable internet connection (preferably with a static IP address, though you could use a dynamic DNS service), and don't mind leaving your computer on whenever you want to play.

It's fairly simple to get set up, and there are instructions on the project web site to help you along. The documentation is fairly detailed, and the application itself is free.

**Multiplayer for Minecraft PE (iOS App)**

[(link to application on iTunes store)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multiplayer-for-minecraft-pe/id609704981)

I can't say much about this, but I've heard that it's fairly simple to use. It saves you having a PC running, but performance would probably be degraded if playing it on the same device you're using for Minecraft PE (if that's even possible?)

---

Either way, neither of these help unless your friend is using them already. And, honestly, chances are that he's not otherwise he'd have told you how to connect.

It doesn't look like there's a way to import an existing world into either of these applications.

Comment: I use the Multiplayer for Minecraft PE app quite often, and I like it. There are options for Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, and 3G/4G.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is!

1. Find ip of that person
2. Type their ip in the box
3. Leave port as is
4. Connect

If it's not connecting make sure you don't get this ip 10.0.0.1 or ips that short you need the long ip for example 12.35.28.56.78