# How far away can you be to play MCPE with someone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I live quite close, but I'm not sure if we are close enough to play together on MCPE multiplayer. Is there a certain distance or does it depend on something else? If there is a certain distance, how far is it?

Comment: With the right setups you can play with people *around the world*. Closeness isn't really a factor. However if you are playing on WiFi, you need to be close enough to connect to the same WiFi, which will depend on several factors; your wireless router, where the router is located, the construction of your home...

Comment: Thank you Trent Hawkins, I couldn't quite word the title, now it's much more understandable!

Comment: The original title was fine-ish, I reviewed a suggested edit that took a stab at it, but removed too much - I added some information back in, and it read a bit better.

Comment: Yeah, it looks a lot better now.

Comment: @Trent Hawkins, I would give you an accept but you answered on comments. But oh well, I've got my answer!

Comment: Regrettably, I'm not particularly familiar with PE, and its networking/servers. I'm familiar enough with computers and networking to offer some general advice in the comments, but I don't know enough about MCPE to provide a good detailed answer (Like setting up a server on your home network, or getting it to work with a VPN).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to play on friend's world in a different part of the country?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174587/is-it-possible-to-play-on-friends-world-in-a-different-part-of-the-country)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Online-Worldwide-Minecraft-PE-Multiplayer):

> Both the Android and iOS versions can play online for free, without the need to install other apps or jailbreak your device

So to answer your question, you can play with anyone regardless of how far away they are, as long as you both have a connection to the internet.

The only thing that the physical distance (from the server) would affect is the [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/1882/106901). However since data travels at the speed of light for most of it's journey the ping should still be at playable levels regardless of location.

---

Steps to play on the internet, for more detail see the [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Online-Worldwide-Minecraft-PE-Multiplayer) or [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojZ-ZoUeIGU)

1. Update Minecraft PE
2. Find the server IP from your browser by searching for *Minecraft PE Servers*. (Listforge is a common one)
3. On your device, open up Minecraft PE, and click play
4. Click the button with the plus sign and the arrow to the left of the advanced button. This is the *Add External Server*
5. Enter any name you wish, the IP or Address and port must be the same as what is listed in the 2nd step.
6. Click *Add Server*
7. Click *Back* and the server should appear in the list and you can now join the server.